# GIT for Windows. All files have a question mark on the icon

Tags: windows, git, repository

I recently installed **Git** onto my **Windows 7** laptop without really knowing what I was doing. The problem I have now is that all the files on my PC have the question mark icon on them as if they needed to committed to a repository.

How can I undo what ever it is that I have done, so that teh files no longer have the question mark icon over them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t use the shell extension, so I could be wrong about this, but I guess the question mark means that the file is untracked. As such it is not part of the repository and Git generally knows nothing about them.

So, you did not do anything, and that is exactly why they have the question mark: They are there, but not part of the repository. You can add them and commit the files and the question mark is probably gone (replaced with a checkmark or something) but of course that depends on what you actually want to do with them.

Comment: So, can you please confirm, it is correct that every file on my computer has this question mark? I would have thought that only applied to files that I have in a repository that have not been committed or added?

Comment: No, that sounds definitely wrong. It should only mark those that are actually in a repository. Unless you have a repository at the top of your drive, this shouldn’t happen.

Comment: Is there any quick way of checking where I have inadvertently made a repository?

Comment: You can open the git bash and then navigate up as long as `git status` will still report some valid output (otherwise it will say that you’re not in a repository).

Comment: Ok, done that, it reports that I have made a repository of my User account on my windows machine. How can I undo this? Accepting your answer even though the relevant information is here in the comments.

Comment: You can simply remove the `.git` folder to remove the repository (without removing the files obviously). You could also try adding a `.gitignore` with `*` as its content to ignore every file, unless you explicitely add it. For the command line this will prevent the files from being listed as untracked, so this could hide them for your visual tool as well.

Answer (score 3):

i got the same problem.
so i tried to find the root of git repository.

i found folder .git at C:\Users\UserName.

you just need to delete or rename it. and the question marks are gone.

Answer (score 3):

It can also happen in case there is a mismatch between the git settings you are having and git repo. 
For ex. if I create a local git repo in a folder and I clone a git repo from one remote git repository in one of the subfolders, then this is a mismatch according to git.

The solution would be not to mix different repo.

Deleting .git is an option but that just means that you have removed the pointer of a wrong repo, in this case, my local repo pointer. Better would be separate out the different git repos.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have some repository which is tracking all your files, and these files with a question mark indicate that the files are untracked.

1. Delete the .git hidden folder in C:\Users\User.Name.
2. Delete the IconCache file C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local from this path.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have set your folders (probably C: drive)to be on a git project, you can try to use `git reset --hard # removes staged and working directory changes`
This will untrack all new files(the files with a quotation mark)
You should execute right click onto your root folder of the project and choose "gitbash here" to execute this command.
And to know where the git reporsitory is located you can search for it typing `*.git` in your main drive, once you find it you'll where your repository is.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue Question Marks on appear on the folders to signify that the file on the local drive does not match any files on the server.

These could be project files or temporary files that don't need to be tracked. They can also be new files the user is creating but has not added to the repository. These files would NOT need to be either committed or reverted before a pull on the Git Server can be performed.

[image]